# __FILE__ pointing to the wrong file in Ruby 2.4.1 under rvm

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a strange problem where `__FILE__` in a gem's executable file is pointing where it shouldn't be (`$PROJECT_ROOT/bin` and not `$GEM_HOME/bin`). It happens with Ruby 2.4.1 but no other versions of MRI Ruby or JRuby. Also, it happens only the script is run from the project root directory. I posted a bug report for the Ruby language at https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14144. Here is that report, pasted below and modified for appropriateness here:

This problem can be illustrated by using the Github repo at https://github.com/keithrbennett/underscore_file_test.

When:

`Ruby version == 2.4.1
  and
current directory is the project root of this project
  and
the gem is built and installed
  and
the executable is run from the gem without preceding it with 'ruby'
  and
the executable is run without specifying a directory
(i.e. as 'underscore_file_test', not 'bin/underscore_file_test')`

then:

```
__FILE__ => $PROJECT_ROOT/exe/underscore_file_test
```

instead of pointing to a directory in the `GEM_PATH`, something like:

```
__FILE__ => /Users/kbennett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/underscore_file_test
```

This error occurred with Ruby 2.4.1 but not:

- `ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [x86_64-darwin15.6.0]`
- `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin16]`
- `ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-darwin16]`
- `jruby 9.1.7.0 (2.3.1) 2017-01-11 68056ae Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.77-b03 on 1.8.0_77-b03 +jit [darwin-x86_64]`

My development machine was a MacBookPro running MacOs Sierra. `uname -a` output is:

```
Darwin MacBook-Pro-KB-13.local 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Wed Oct 4 00:17:00 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.71.6~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Steps to Reproduce:

```
1) Download or git clone the Github project tree, or the attached tarball.
2) Change directory to the project root.
3) Run: clear; gem build *gemspec && gem install *gem && underscore_file_test
4) Note the directory component of the output.
```

If you cd somewhere else, the output will be correct,
i.e. will be located in a `GEM_PATH` directory.

If you run the command from the project root using a different Ruby,
it may work. I have not tested this on versions later than 2.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been an rvm issue.  When I would gem uninstall rvm's executable_hooks gem, the behavior would be correct; and when I'd reinstall it, it would be incorrect again.

I did an `rvm remove 2.4.1` and then a `rvm install 2.4.1 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl`, and the problem disappeared.

Note that it was necessary to do `rvm remove` and not just `rvm uninstall`. See https://rvm.io/rubies/removing for an explanation of the difference.

Answer (score 0):

The `__FILE__` indication may actually be a symlink, not the actual destination file. To find out the file you're actually pointing to you may need to resolve it:

```
file = __FILE__
while (File.symlink?(file))
  file = File.readlink(file)
end
```

This will keep following symlinks until it hits the original. This typically only applies to symlinked binaries, something RVM and tools like it often do, but not library files which are usually left as-is in their usual place.

You can test that this code is working correctly by making a symlink to your binary stub and calling that directly:

```
ln -s test.rb symlink.rb
ruby symlink.rb
```

You'll get the correct path that way.

Ruby's `require_relative` does seem to handle this for you, but if you're manually constructing paths using `__FILE__` you'll have to keep this in mind when resolving.

Comment: Interesting. It's the `gem install` that's creating the file that is called, and if it was creating a symlink to the project source, that's a serious problem. After removing and reinstalling 2.4.1, I am unable to reproduce the problem so unfortunately I can't test this hypothesis.